# How can I make a header like for facebook?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to a make a header exactly like for  facebook but when I make it fixed its content inside starts changing position on window resize .
Like here http://www.housetostay.co.za/
how can I fix this 
Below is my code

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .heading { 
      display:block;
      top:0px;
      left:0px;
      right:0px;
      height:20px;
      position:fixed;
      border:1px solid #888;
      padding:0px;
      text-align:center;
      font-weight:bold;
      color:#000;
      background: #ccc;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100px;
      z-index:3;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class = "heading">
    <table id ="headertable" align="left">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="http://www.housetostay.co.za">
            <h2 class= "logo">HouseToStay</h2>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </a>
        </td>
        <td><a href="http://www.housetostay.co.za" class="button middle">How it works</a></td>
        <td><a href="http://www.housetostay.co.za" class="button middle">Contact us</a></td>
        <td><a href="register.php" class="button middle">PostAd</a></td>
        <td><a href="jobs.php" class="button middle">Jobs</a></td>
        <td><a href="http://www.housetostay.co.za" class="button middle">Buy it</a></td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </table>
    <table class ="profile">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <h2>user</h2>
      </td>
      <td>
        <img src="bhubezi/images/logos/nopic.png" width="50" height="40">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: So does your code work? Are you having problems with it?

Comment: The content inside the heading div move on resize

Comment: Try to add margin:0px auto;

Comment: @NorbertPisz on that same div?

Comment: Not sure if it has to do with your problem, but you have some errors in that html you posted. There's a td within an anchor and the first table is missing the closing tr tag.

Comment: @Cluster the edit was essential thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try do this by jQuery.

Here You have a simple [Demo](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/demo/jquery/scroll-fix-header-facebook/)

Here you have a [Tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/scroll-fix-header-jquery-facebook/)

This sample wroks fine when resizing page.

Answer (score 1):

Using `<table>` for layout is generally frowned upon, and in this case makes it harder to achieve what you're trying to do.  I would recommend replacing your `<table>`-based layout with more standard HTML elements (for example, by putting your menu into a list `<ul>` and your user profile into its own `<div>`), then absolutely positioning those elements and giving them explicit pixel positions.  Then they shouldn't move around when you resize the window.

Here's an example (using your own code with as few modifications as possible):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.heading { 
    display:block;top:0px;left:0px;right:0px;height:20px;position:fixed;border:1px solid #888;padding:0px;text-align:center;font-weight:bold;color:#000;background: #ccc;width: 100%;height: 100px;z-index:3;
}

#logo {
    position:absolute; /* This will keep it one place */
    left:200px; /* This specifies what place */
}

#menu {
    position:absolute; /* This will keep it one place */
    left:320px; /* This specifies what place */
    width:400px; /* This makes sure the menu doesn't shrink if the window is made smaller */
    list-style-type:none;
}

#menu li {
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
}

#profile {
    position:absolute; /* This will keep it one place */
    left:750px; /* This specifies what place */
    width:100px; /* This makes sure the profile doesn't shrink if the window is made smaller */
}

#profile h2 {
    display:inline;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="heading">
    <a href="http://www.housetostay.co.za" id="logo">
        <h2>HouseToStay</h2>
    </a>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="http://www.housetostay.co.za" class="button middle">How it works</a>    </li>
        <li><a href="http://www.housetostay.co.za" class="button middle">Contact us</a></li>
        <li><a href="register.php" class="button middle">PostAd</a></li>
        <li><a href="jobs.php" class="button middle">Jobs</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.housetostay.co.za" class="button middle">Buy it</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="profile">
        <h2>user</h2>
        <img src="bhubezi/images/logos/nopic.png" width="50" height="40">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit**: added explicit pixel positions to header elements.

Comment: ok great Idea but i tried it does not work anyway I will keep on trying

Comment: @humphrey I edited the example text to solve what I think is your problem; let me know if that works.

Comment: You a star and I wanna ask if I want now to put the content and sidebar dives should I pu them under those divs? and please invite me on Google talk kingmusa5 at gmail dot com

Comment: Yes, content and sidebar `div`s would be best put beneath the header `div`.  But if you need more specific help then you should either open a new question (if it's a general technical issue appropriate to Stack Overflow), look at online tutorials on web design, or seek the assistance of a web programmer.